# Data sent back to client is returning 'undefined'

Tags: javascript

I have a callable cloud function that appears to be functioning completely correctly, apart from the message I'm sending back to the client returning as `undefined`.

My current setup looks like this:

Function call from the client:

```
 const myFunction = async => {
    let fn = firebase.functions().httpsCallable("testFunction");
    try {
      const response = await fn({ sentData: some_data});
      console.log(response.data.backendResult);
    } catch (err) {
      alert(err);
    }
  };
```

Cloud function call:

```
// functions/index.js

exports.testFunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

 const { otherFunc } = require("./otherFunc");
 ...
 return otherFunc(arg, { backendResult: "success" });
}

// functions/otherFunc.js

const otherFunc = async (
  someDoc,
  obj
) => {
  try {
    await someDoc.set(
      {
        content: "test"
      }
    );
    console.log(obj.backendResult);
    return obj.backendResult;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

module.exports = { otherFunc};
```

The data is writing correctly to Firestore, and `obj.backendResult` is logging correctly in my logs, but the data is returning `undefined` in the client.

Comment: Not a Google cloud expert, but in your `otherFunc` function, shouldn't you be returning `obj` instead of `obj.backendResult;`?

Comment: yep, that worked. ty

Comment: Glad it worked! I posted the above comment as an answer in case it could help someone else, so please consider marking it as the answer if it helped. Have a good day
!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a Google cloud expert, but in your `otherFunc` function, shouldn't you be returning `obj` instead of `obj.backendResult`?